# Firebase Error Message - The document has moved https://fcm.googleapis.com/batch?google_abuse=GOOGLE_ABUSE_EXEMPTION

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

We are sending lots and lots of FCM Messages to our millions of users. As the message is triggered by an external event (Kick off in a football match) we sent many messages at the same time.

Sometimes the sending of an FCM message fails and we get an error message like this:

```
<H1>302 Moved</H1> The document has moved 
<A HREF="https://fcm.googleapis.com/batch? 
google_abuse=GOOGLE_ABUSE_EXEMPTION%3DID%....3B+expires%3DTue,+22-Nov- 
2022+19:04:17+GMT">here</A>. </BODY></HTML>
```

(I removed some text for privacy reasons.)

For sending the messages we use

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:9.1.0'
```

We got thousands of error messages like this in one minute. In the next minute everthing worked fine again.

I have search the internet for information about it. But i couldn't find any abuse rules for FCM. Does anybody has information about this kind of error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*firebaser here*

At first glance, your project may be getting throttled, but it may also be another problem in the API calls or the FCM backend. It’ll be challenging to pinpoint or even narrow down what is the specific cause of the error on a public forum without going into project-specific details. I would recommend reaching out to [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support) as they can offer personalized help. Please provide the latest request and response *(with timestamp)* you have so they can check what happened to the message delivery.